# starting an activity in a onListItemClick()

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

Hello I am new to Android app development and recently I am developing an app. My app contains a listview in which I have added a String array.My objective is that When I click on a particular item in that list I want to share that item. For example if my listview contains these particular set of strings like "Apple", "Banana" ,"Orange" and if I click Banana I want the text "banana" to be shared among other apps like gmail, email, facebook, etc. The problem is that I get my lisview properly. All the items are being displayed but when i click on a particular item the sharing intent is not called. Pls help. I will add my code also. Thanks in advance

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits));
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, fruits[position]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `startActivity`

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: yeah I used it and now it is working. Thank you so much sir :)

Answer (score 1):

As others said you have to use startActivity or startActivtyForResult if your current activity needs some data to get back from the intented activity.

Comment: it is working after using startActivity. Thanks a lot :)